# phpUnit and models which inherit ADODB_Active_Record, stubbing ADODB_mysql

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, adodb

I've searched high and low and, astonishingly, cannot find an answer.

When trying to unit test my models with phpUnit how can I stub the database?

I'm using a PHP framework CMS which has a number of classes which inherit from a class ("Model") which inherits from ADODB_Active_Record. Model's constructor grabs a db object (from ADOConnection) and passes it to Active_Record's constructor.

It might not be Best Practice, but in order to change the code as little as possible, I'm thinking of tweaking grabDBObject()  to return a stub object when in testing. That stub gets passed to ADODB_Active_Record, and, in theory, I can test my models.

However, I can't figure out how to create the stub. ADODB_Connection isn't simple. It's not going to be a matter of replacing Execute(). There are a bunch of other functions, like qstr(), that it appears I'll have to worry about and rewrite as necessary.

What's surprising is I can't find any discussions of people doing this. This has got to be a common problem. Am I going in the wrong direction? I understand that I can use something like dbUnit to actually do db queries rather than stubbing ADODB_connection, but I also understand that I should stub as much as possible, and that it's bad to rely on a db for unit tests of a model's methods.

So,
1. Should I be stubbing the db connection for unit testing?
2. How?

Comment: This isn't a good answer, so I'll make it a comment because I have no idea if this will work for you or not: But have you tried SQL Lite? A lot of .Net developers use that as a replacement RDBMS during testing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to avoid sqlite and any other databases that I would have to "depend" on (though I know sqlite is a bit different). More importantly, though, when I did try sqlite, I found that there were a lot of schema and db calls that are mysql specific and not easily modified (this is part of a larger FOSS CMS).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the getMock() method of phpunit ?

It allows you to provide a fake object for testing, without touching your production code.

But in that case, you have to build the expected result by yourself.

The doc is here :

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html

Comment: That's exactly the problem I'm having. It appears that I don't want a mock so much as a stub (mock being used to check that methods get called, according to docs). But, as I stated, "ADODB_Connection" isn't very simple. I can't just stub/mock the Execute() method, etc....